# Neo4j match using a list

Tags: neo4j, nosql

i have a node like this: (:a{name:'',lname:'',listNumb:[1,3,9]})
i want to select when 1 is in the array

this is what  itried to do
`match (:a ) where a.listNumb=1 return a ; or  match (:a {listNumb=1})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IN` to check if a value is present in the array/list.

```
MATCH (n:a) 
WHERE 1 IN n.listNumb  
RETURN n;
```